# Operating an inductor beyond its rated current

Tags: inductor

Let's assume the following situation: there is a power supply which VCC line has an inductor between some capacitors, for additional filtering capabilities:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fojvyU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is [RLB0712-101KL](https://www.bourns.com/pdfs/RLB.pdf) which rated DC current is 320 mA.

My question is - what will happen if I try to put a load of 1.5A at 15V through it? My vague vision of it - it is going to heat, maybe even blow, also the inductance value will drop at such current. I'd be grateful for a more detailed explanation of what will happen.

Comment: The data sheet tells you the ohms so calculate the power at 1.5 amps then make your mind up if it will melt. Speak to the supplier about the curie point of the magnetics and see if the temperature it rises to (but not melts) will permanently wreck the inductance.

Comment: What happens to an inductor outside it's specified current range is that it **saturates** magnetically. The magnetic field will be at it's maximum strength and cannot increase anymore. Now the idea of an inductor in your circuit is that it tries to stabilize the current and resist current changes. But it can only do that when it is **not saturated**. In fact a saturated inductor behaves as a resistor so it will not do much at all ! If that resistance is high enough to generate enough heat then indeed, it might melt or smoke.

Comment: @Andyaka Why would reaching the curie point wreck the inductor? It's not supposed to have any permanent magnetic field in the first place.

Comment: @dmitry doesn't the permeability fall to low and unrecoverable values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The temperature rise is stated to be 20°C at maximum current. You are suggesting putting 4.7 times as much current, so it should rise more than 400°C, which will destroy the wire insulation causing it to melt together with shorted turns. After some time it may open up. The inductance will also drop **dramatically** due to core saturation and will be little better than a very high resistance unreliable wire.

You do not need an inductor in this position, and 100uH is too low to make any significant difference at mains frequencies anyway (\$X_L = 2\pi f\cdot L \approx 0.075\Omega \$ at 120Hz).

A short would be an infinitely better choice.

Your capacitors are also very low for 1.5A current- more than 8Vp-p ripple at 1.5A, and you'll probably truncate their life with all that ripple current.

Comment: I found an article about filter cap calculation - http://www.electroschematics.com/7048/capacitor-input-filter-calculation/

Applying these formulas to my needs it seems I need at least 50000 uF capacitor to get low voltage ripple. Maybe there are better circuits to get 15V 2A then the one I draw?

Comment: At 30W you should be using a switching supply, but the complexity goes up considerably. Consider using a wall plug adapter switching supply.

Comment: So there is actually no way to achieve low ripple using linear supply with a reasonable capacitor size? There are lots of circuits of it in the internet, for example LM337-based: http://www.circuitdiagramworld.com/power_supply_circuit_diagram/Power_supply_12_V_5A__based_on_an_LM338_10233.html - cap is only 13600 uF. How can that thing work at high current?

Comment: Yes there is, but the regulator will have to waste a lot of heat, maybe more than 10W. 10,000 uF or so is enough- 1.2Vp-p ripple. The ripple will be reduced by 54-70dB for inputs more than 18.5V. But if you give it (say) 23V nominal to account for line voltage and ripple, the dissipation will be  about 12W. That's a lot of waste and a lot of heat to get rid of. Ripple on the regulator output should be < 1mV RMS.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds acceptable - I use a metal case as a heatsink so I think 10W dissipation should be ok. Will try to measure regulator input and output ripple tomorrow, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It can be difficult to predict how these sorts of parts will behave outside their datasheet parameters because they don't describe specifics of their magnetic design: material, volume, turns, etc.

So, we can focus on what *is* specified.

The temperature rise is specified as 20 Celsius at the rated current of 320mA.

At \$ 320mA \$, with a winding resistance of \$ 400 m \Omega \$,

\$ P = I^2 R = (0.320A)^2 \cdot 400 m\Omega = 40.9mW \$

At \$ 1.5A \$, with a winding resistance of \$ 400 m \Omega \$,

\$ P = I^2 R = (1.5A)^2 \cdot 400 m\Omega = 900mW \$

Your conclusions about heating and possibly blowing are sound.

Another consideration: at 1.5A, the winding resistance will drop  0.6V which will need to be considered in terms of headroom for your linear regulator.

Finally, in general,these sorts of inductors are meant to operate at the specified DC current with a small amount of AC ripple on them (typically 20% of the rated DC current) to avoid saturation. At such a heavy overload I doubt that there would be much inductance left all.

Summary: get a better inductor.

Comment: I think I'll just short capactitors positive pins, as I don't have a high-current rated inductor at the moment :( Thanks.